# Cannot create new MySQL database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having issues trying to create a new MySQL database in php,

my code is:

```
<?php
   $dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = ‘somepassword’;

   $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
   if(!$conn->connect_error )
   {
     die('Could not connect: %s' . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   echo "Connected successfully\n";


   $sql = "CREATE DATABASE TUTORIALS2";

   if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){

     echo "Created the database\n";

   }

   else {
     echo "Failed to create the database".$conn->error;
   }



   //Close the database
   $conn->close();


 ?>
```

MySQL connects fine but it won't allow me to create a new database. Not a clue what I'm doing wrong here. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `mysql_*` are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: edited my question for mysqli, still having the same issue

Comment: Mysql_error, did that get converted too?

Comment: @DrewPierce sorry updated that. Still no luck.

Comment: Look at what Alex answered. Once enabled look at logs or errors on devtest output

Comment: Wasn't that, has always connected fine. Just won't create the database now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second Edit:
I somehow missed this, apologies.

You have a mistake here:

`if(!$conn->connect_error )`

should be

`if($conn->connect_error )`

see here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

---

Edit:

run this query `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';` either from php or from PhpMyAdmin or similar and see if the user root has the privilege to create databases.

More here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html

---

First of all you need to [enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) [error_reporting](http://hp.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and second you have some bad quotes on this line
`$dbpass = ‘somepassword’;`

replace like this

`$dbpass = 'somepassword';`

Comment: not sure why I had the bad quotes, maybe because I copied and pasted from a command line editor. Fixed it though and it's not that. It always connects fine, just won't create a database

Comment: AH! That helped me find the error! turns out the database wasn't connecting at all. I had "localhost:3036" just changed it to "localhost" and now everything works! thanks!